# Removing from a custom data type Vector array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

Having a really hard time trying to remove from my Customer vector array.

It's defined as:

```
vector<Customer> VecCustomerCollection;
```

Customer is an object (which stores information of each customer)

Currently trying to remove like so:

```
VecCustomerCollection.erase(emove(VecCustomerCollection.begin(), VecCustomerCollection.end(), cus), VecCustomerCollection.end());
```

But that gives a lot of errors (i read that i need to overload it, but not sure how)

I've also tried the approach of using an iterator and iterating through the vector (as each value is unique).

However also won't work, and tried all afternoon to get it to work.

Any insight on how to get it to work? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to define `operator ==` for class `Customer` or to define some predicate that will be a substitution for this operator. In the last case you have to use algorithm `std::remove_if` instead of `std::remove`.

Shortly speaking you should decide how you will compare objects of type Customer with each other. The compiler is unable to decide instead of you how to compare the objects.

Take into account that there is a typo

```
VecCustomerCollection.erase(emove(VecCustomerCollection...
                            ^^
```

Comment: How would i define operator ==?

Comment: @rawrsquid_x I know neither how the class Customer is defined nor how you are going to compare two objects of the class. So I can say nothing.

Comment: The customer class is like so: http://pastebin.com/ZTCUsYGU.
Just a basic class with getters, and a few extra functions. I'm not sure how we'd compare the objects either. The class I'm working on currently is like so: http://pastebin.com/SdYbrVtu - As you can see we're just passing in a customer object, and adding it to the vector.

Comment: I've just added:

`bool operator==(const Customer &lcs, const Customer &rcs)
    {
        if (lcs == rcs) return true;
            else return false;
    }`

But still getting the error: `error: no match for 'operator==' in 'it == c`

at:

`if (it == c)`

Comment: @rawrsquid_x Your operator is invalid because it calls recursively itself in statement if ( lcs == rcs ). It is what you have to write. What does mean lcs == rcs?